# How to make subdomain server file from other host in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying this in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine 
RewriteRule /mymedia/sample.mp3 http://somedomain.com/file/sample.mp3 [NC,L]
```

But its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`RewriteRule` in `.htaccess` doesn't match leading slash `/`**

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mymedia/sample\.mp3$ http://somedomain.com/file/sample.mp3 [R,NC,L]
```

**OR if file names are same as shown in your example:**

```
RewriteRule ^mymedia/(sample\.mp3)$ http://somedomain.com/file/$1 [R,NC,L]
```

**EDIT To allow space in target file name:**

```
RewriteRule ^mymedia/file\.mp3$ http://somedomain.com/file/my\ file.mp3 [R,NC,L]
```

Comment: i tried and its not working. i have sapce in file path like  /file/my file.mp3

Comment: You should put all these requirements in your question upfront. Anyway try the edited code now.

Comment: sorry for that . i mean my url is `file.mp3` but url on remote contains space like `my file.mp3`

Comment: See edit now: `RewriteRule ^mymedia/file\.mp3$ http://somedomain.com/file/my\ file.mp3 [R,NC,L]`